Inconsistent results for average request time per request URL in Grafana+Nginx+Loki
I am using stack of Nginx + Loki + Prometheus + Grafana. I tried to implement a table which will show average request time grouped by the URL. I came up with this query
avg_over_time({filename="$filename", host="$host"} | json | request_uri =~ "^/api.*" | unwrap request_time | __error__="" [$__interval]) by (request_uri) * 1000

The result looks promising but I noticed that is completely wrong

Why is it wrong:

I know how much time each request takes and these values just seem totally off,
Changing time range drastically changes the results. It almost feels like for smaller time range each time I select 2x bigger range I get 2x bigger averages. This does not seem right at all.

Apart from that I noticed that here I can choose some values and it seems to have great impact on the results I am getting but none of the combinations I've tried seem right

I've tried to replace [$__interval] with hard-coded value like 5m or 1d and it also has great impact on the values I am seeing but again - none of them seem right.

Turns out that in the second tab Transform data I had Total as Calculations.
Choosing Mean solved the problem
